Does rvalue reference as parameter call the move constructor?
I'm learning about C++ move semantics, and I have trouble understanding the code below:
#include <iostream>
class A {
    public:
        A() { std::cout << "Default Constructor\n"; }
        A(const A& other) { std::cout << "Copy Constructor\n"; }
        A(A&& other) noexcept { std::cout << "Move Constructor\n"; }
    
        // 仅仅是为了避免编译器优化而定义
        A& operator=(const A& other) {
            std::cout << "Copy Assignment Operator\n";
            return *this;
        }
        A& operator=(A&& other) noexcept {
            std::cout << "Move Assignment Operator\n";
            return *this;
        }
    };
    
    void func(A&& a) {
        // Do something with 'a'
    }
    
    int main() {
        A a;  // 调用默认构造函数
        func(std::move(a));  // 调用移动构造函数
        func(A());  // 直接传递右值，调用移动构造函数
        return 0;
    }

The output is:
Default Constructor
Default Constructor

Why is the move constructor not being called? Why is only two default constructors being called?
The compiler is "g++ 13.2"


std::move does not move (it is just a typecast to an rvalue reference). The first Default Constructor calls is from A a; and the second one is from func(A()) (where you create an instance of A for the duration of the call).

To call the move constructor you must do something like A(std::move(A()) or create a function A getA() { return A(); } and then call A(getA()). Also read the documentation on std::move std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from"

A&& that you receive in the function is a mere reference. At this point no object is constructed, so no constructor is run. To call the move constructor, you would need to create a new object. Try to run A a2(a); inside func

Thank you very much!!!!! I get it/(ㄒoㄒ)/~~

@AlexeyS.Larionov you mean A a2(std::move(a)) inside func

@Caleth absolutely, ty for correcting me!

Think about it. Does lreference as parameter call the copy constructor?

void func(A&& a) { }

int main() {
        A a;  // default constructor
        func(std::move(a));  // you are merely creating a reference that allows moving.
                             // Your func doesn't do anything with it, so no object is created/moved.
        func(A());  // again, you create an object (default constructor), then pass it
                    // to func() as a reference that would allow moving.
        return 0;
    }

Things would be very different if you changed your func to take an actual object:
void func(A a) { }

Now, your moves would actually be used to populate that new a:
func(a);               // copy your a into the function parameter
func(std::move(a));    // move your a into the function parameter



Why is the move constructor not being called? Why is only two default constructors being called?

Nothing in your example requires the use of the move ctor for the creation of objects of type A.
In particular, A a; is default initialization so the default ctor will be used.
Further, the std::move in the statement func(std::move(a)); just returns an rvalue reference and doesn't actually move or create an object.
Lastly, the call func(A());  first uses the default ctor for the A() part to create a temporary A object, which results in an rvalue expression that can directly bind to the A&& parameter. Here again, there is no need for the move ctor to be used.
